# Get inflate ViewGroup of a layout with fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

I'm actually programming an Android app that uses Google Maps API.

The layout activity_main.xml looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          map:mapType="normal"
          map:uiCompass="false"
          map:uiRotateGestures="true"
          map:uiScrollGestures="true"
          map:uiTiltGestures="true"
          map:uiZoomControls="false"
          map:uiZoomGestures="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And I load the map asynchronically in the fragment. When I try to inflate the activity_main view:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
ViewGroup mainView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
```

The app crashes and returns an error:

```
01-15 19:25:16.045: E/AndroidRuntime(21115): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
```

How can i solve it? I need this ViewGroup to set a Power Button KeyListener to the app (similar to what I did in another app without fragment):

```
mainView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        {
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)
            {
                //STUFF
            }
        }
    });
```

Thank you for your help :D

Comment: Looks like you're trying to reinvent the wheel.. the wrong way. You need to add a listener to a view? is it the map view? Create custom map fragment and override `onViewCreated(View, Bundle)`. The view in parameters is the map view. Also don't ever use an inflater from application context unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: I've posted another code in the answers, check what's my problem right now.

Comment: How about posting another question instead?

Comment: I will do that then.

Answer (score 0):

namespace must be declared in the first view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      map:mapType="normal"
      map:uiCompass="false"
      map:uiRotateGestures="true"
      map:uiScrollGestures="true"
      map:uiTiltGestures="true"
      map:uiZoomControls="false"
      map:uiZoomGestures="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't fix my problem. The application is still crashing with the same error.

Comment: sorry just realized the error, you can not inflate fragments, fragments are handled by the fragment transaction, You can not do this MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) mainView.find ....

Comment: Ok, so how can I handle a fragment in order to set some Key Listeners to the app?

Comment: if activity_main is part of their activity, use findViewById for the LinearLayout, because you can not put listener in the fragment, this would be within the fragment

Comment: I tried to do this:
mainView = (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.mapContainer);
Where mapContainer is the LinearLayout id, and I tried to put the listener on that ViewGroup. But the OnKeyListener is never triggered (I tried to print something in the Debug)

Comment: there are some listener having the activity to the keyboard could use the method onKeyDown Activity

Comment: I know, but I want to get the Power Key button, so I have to use the onKeyListener :\

Comment: Might extend  fragment and override the method onCreateView, and put the view to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this lines in your manifest file:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR_KEY" />
```

Take a look on this site
https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw

Comment: Maybe you don't understand my problem. The maps works perfectly, I just need to get the inflated ViewGroup in the Activity in order to put some Key Listeners for the app.

Answer (score 0):

I've almost solved the problem. I've created a custom SupportMapFragment class and I'm loading the fragment in a FrameLayout dynamically.

The activity_main.xml looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapPlaceholder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I can now inflate the activity_main through code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
ViewGroup mainView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
```

After this, I've set the listener (100% working):

```
mainView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
mainView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() 
{
       @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        {
            //STUFF
        }
    });
```

And I've added the view like this:

```
final WindowManager myWindowManager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
myWindowManager.addView(mainView, viewParams);
```

I'm not using the setContentView anywhere in onCreate so here's the second problem. I need to load the GoogleMap in the FrameLayout through FragmentTransaction.

FragmentTransaction needs setContentView to work. This code:

```
FrameLayout mapPlaceholder = (FrameLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.mapPlaceholder);

if(mapPlaceholder != null) {
    mapFragment = GoogleMapFragment.newInstance();

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(mapPlaceholder.getId(), mapFragment, GoogleMapFragment.class.getName());
    ft.commit();
}
```

Returns this error when launching the application:

```
01-16 18:22:20.263: E/AndroidRuntime(7755): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f070018 (com.example.app:id/mapPlaceholder) for fragment GoogleMapFragment{b666a7d #0 id=0x7f070018 com.example.app.GoogleMapFragment}
```

Does anyone know how to use the FragmentTransaction (or add a Fragment) without setContentView?